# DynamoDB use case handling

Tags: amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I am using dynamoDB for a project. I have a use case where I maintain timeline for objects i.e. start and end time for an object and start time for next object. New objects can be added in between two existing objects(o1 & o2) in which I will have to update start time for next object in o1 and start time for next object in new object as start time of o2. This can cause problem in case two new objects are being added in between two objects and would probably require transactions. Can someone suggest how this can be handled?

Update: My data model looks like this:
objectId(Hash Key), startTime(Sort Key), endTime, nextStartTime
1, 1, 5, 4
1, 4, 6, 8
1, 8, 10, 9

So, it's possible a new entry comes in whose start time is 5. So, in transaction I will have to update nextStartTime for second entry to 5 and insert a new entry after the second entry which contains nextStartTime as start time of third entry. During this another entry might come in which also has start time between second and third entry(say 7 for eg.). Now I want the two transactions to be isolated of each other. In traditional SQL DBs it would be possible as second entry would be locked for the duration of transaction but Dynamo doesn't lock the items. So, I am wondering if I use transaction would the two transactions protect the data integrity.

Comment: @jarmod Would transaction provide sufficient isolation in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB supports optimistic locking. This is achieved via conditional writes.

You can do it manually by introducing a version attribute or you can use the one provided (hopefully) by your SDK. Here is a [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html) to AWS docs.

TLDR

- two objects have to update the same timeline at the same time
- one will succeed the other will fail with a specific error
- you will have to retry the failing one

Dynamo also has [transactions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html). However, they are limited to 25 elements and consume 2x capacity units. If you can get away with an optimistic lock go for it.

Hope this was helpful

Update with more info on transactions
From [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html)

> Error Handling for Writing Write transactions don't succeed under the
> following circumstances:
>
> When a condition in one of the condition expressions is not met.
>
> When a transaction validation error occurs because more than one
> action in the same TransactWriteItems operation targets the same item.
>
> When a TransactWriteItems request conflicts with an ongoing
> TransactWriteItems operation on one or more items in the
> TransactWriteItems request. In this case, the request fails with a
> TransactionCanceledException.
>
> When there is an insufficient provisioned capacity for the transaction to
> be completed.
>
> When an item size becomes too large (larger than 400 KB), or a local
> secondary index (LSI) becomes too large, or a similar validation error
> occurs because of changes made by the transaction.
>
> When there is a user error, such as an invalid data format.

They claim that if there are two ongoing transactions on the same item, one will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link! This seems useful if we are doing multiple read and updates. But in my case I have to do update item o1 + insert item o1' which contains data read from o2. I think I may have to read up on how transactions are handled in dynamo as locking is not suported int it.

Comment: Perhaps this can also help
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html

Comment: Have updated with more info. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Borislav. I was able to solve the use case as you suggested with the help of manual optimistic locking and transactions. I had to solve an edge case of concurrent first insert for a given hashkey by inserting a zero version entry with conditional check that version attribute not exists.

Answer (score 2):

Why store the `nextStartTime` in the item? The `nextStartTime` is simply the start time of the next item, right? Seems like it'd be much easier to just pull the item as well as the next item to get the full picture at read-time. With a Query you can do this in one call, and so long as items are less than 2 KB in size it wouldn't even consume more RCUs than a get item would.

Simpler design, no cost for transactional writes, no need to do extensive testing on thread safety.